# Getting the error "Project not found. Resource readiness deadline exceeded" when trying to create a cloud run service only on certain project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

When I try to create a cloud run service, I am running into the error:

```
 Project not found. Resource readiness deadline exceeded
```

This problem only happens on one project.  I have looked into the logs and all I am provided with is:

```
Ready condition status changed to False for Revision hello-00002-leb with message: Missing Resource: '[name=hello, project=<the name of my project>, region=us-central1, kind=ROUTE]' is required to complete actions on '[name=hello-00002-leb, project=<the name of my project>, region=us-central1, kind=REVISION]'
```

I dug deeper and found that the google cloud api shows that I am getting a 400 response code for google.cloud.run.v1.Revisions.GetRevision 100% of the time.

I am using the hello test image (which I have confirmed is in the correct place.

I am a Cloud Run Admin.

How do I get this to work? please help